# TSQL if no data then NULL on date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an application where there are multiple date fields that can be edited by an Admin when needed. The query updates every field in the table updating it with any new information.

By default, my 3 date fields are empty in the table. When I run my update query, even though I don't add a date it updates the column to:

```
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

My update statement is here:

```
UPDATE tuitionSubmissions
SET reimbursementDate = COALESCE (@reimbursementDate, NULL),
    empGradDate       = COALESCE (@gradDate, NULL),
    payPeriod         = COALESCE (@payPeriod, NULL),
    [status]          = @status,
    notes             = @notes,
    managerApproval   = @empID,
    approvalDate      = COALESCE (GETDATE(), NULL)
WHERE id = @tid;`
```

From my understanding, I thought that if those variables are empty then it would just keep the field NULL.

Is there another way to do this making it so the date field remains NULL until an actual date / value is sent to the stored procedure?

Comment: Is the field nullable? You can check with SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('TableName', 'U'), 'ColumnName', 'AllowsNull');

Comment: Looks like the client code is passing a non-null value of zero (0) to the update statement. Try changing the coalesce statements to :
`NullIf(@reimbursementDate, '1 jan 1900')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of `COALESCE` is meaningless. It same as `IF @reimbursementDate IS NULL THEN NULL`.
Use it like this:

```
SET reimbursementDate = COALESCE (@reimbursementDate, reimbursementDate)
```

In this case the column will stay unchanged if parameter not passed (i.e. parameter is `NULL`)

Comment: I updated it to this however as soon as I send other fields to the database, it updates those fields from NULL to 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000

Comment: This worked, didnt notice my vars was set as varchar and not datetime